# Probability of guessing correct gender in two scenarios

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose there is a family with two children. The family tells me that at least one child is a boy, and wants me to guess the gender of the other child. Let's say there are two things I can do: I can either guess right away, or I can ask whether the boy is the first or the second child, and then I can guess accordingly. If both children are boys, then they answer randomly with first or second.

If in both cases my guess is that the other child is a girl, here are the possibilities for each case:

**Case 1**:
Because I do not know which child is a boy, the possibilities are BB, BG and GB. Since they are all equally probable, the probability that I got right is $\frac 2 3$.

**Case 2**:
In this case I asked whether the boy is the first or the second child. If they give the answer 'first', then the possibilities are BB and BG, so the probability that I got right is $\frac 1 2$. This would be equivalent to the case in which I knew beforehand that the first child is a boy and guessed accordingly. If they give the answer 'second', then the probability that I got right is analogously $\frac 1 2$.

So, in case 1 the probability that I got right is $\frac 2 3$, and in case 2 the probability  is $\frac 1 2$, although in both cases I guessed 'girl' no matter what the answer I got in case 2 is. Just the mere fact that I asked that question and got an answer to it reduced my possibility of getting the answer right. How is this possible? There must be something I am missing or miscalculating.

Comment: this is not clear.  Who is "the boy"?  In the initial claim "at least one of the two children is a boy" there is no reference to a specific child (that's the source of all the confusion).  If you can ask about the gender of the eldest child, then that is clear enough.  But I don't know what the second case means.  What exact question are you posing?

Comment: The family does not reveal to me which child is "the boy". If their first child is the boy and the second child is a girl, they answer with 'first'. If the first is girl and the second is boy, they answer with 'second'. If both are boys, then they answer either with 'first' or 'second'.

Comment: So, then hearing First there is a $\frac 23$ chance that it came from the $BG$ case.  the ways to hear First are:  You had $BG$ initially or you had $BB$ and decided to say "first" on a coin toss.  The first scenario has probability $\frac 13$ and the second has probability $\frac 13\times 12=\frac 16$.

Comment: But what is the difference between 1) first knowing that one child is a boy and then learning that the first child is a boy, and 2) first knowing that the first child is a boy? In 2), the answer would be $\frac 1 2$. Why is not the same for 1)?

Comment: Because the first question specifies a child (you are precisely asking about the first child) and the second does not.

Comment: To avoid confusion:  I am saying that, in the second case (where you  fail to specify a child), the probability is $\frac 23$ that the unnamed child is a girl.  You learn nothing useful from hearing "First".

Comment: You are skipping over steps.  The reason the Boy/Girl probability questions generate so much confusion is that people rush through the steps and don't bother to specify what is going on.  The answer to the first one is $\frac 12$ because hearing "Boy" in response to the question "what is the gender of the Eldest child", can only have come from the states $BG$ and $BB$.  Both of these states have probability $\frac 13$ and in both cases you are certain to hear the answer "Boy".  Bayes does the rest.

Comment: Even the initial statement "the parents tell me that at least one child is a boy" is problematic. Why would anyone say such an odd thing?  Are they more or less likely to say such an odd thing if both are boys or if exactly one was a boy?  Better, I think, to imagine that you asked the question "is at least one of your children a boy?" and received the answer Yes.  Keep all questions binary, with only one truthful reply.

Comment: I get what I was missing now, thanks a lot for your nice explanations. :)

Comment: You exclude NB folks? Azokhen Wey!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your case 1:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Older} & \text{Younger} &  \text{Statement 1}  & \text{Probability}  \\ \hline
\text{Girl} & \text{Girl} & \text{No boys} &  \frac14\\ \hline 
\text{Boy} & \text{Girl} & \text{At least 1 boy}  & \frac14\\  \hline
\text{Girl} & \text{Boy} & \text{At least 1 boy}  & \frac14\\ \hline
\text{Boy} & \text{Boy} & \text{At least 1 boy}  & \frac14\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

so the conditional probability given the statement "At least $1$ boy" of both being boys is $\dfrac{\frac14}{\frac14+\frac14+\frac14}=\dfrac13$.

Here is your case 2:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|} 
\text{Older} & \text{Younger} &  \text{Statement 1} & \text{Statement 2} & \text{Probability}  \\ \hline
\text{Girl} & \text{Girl} & \text{No boys} &  \text{Neither is a boy} & \frac14\\ \hline 
\text{Boy} & \text{Girl} & \text{At least 1 boy} &  \text{Older is a boy} & \frac14\\  \hline
\text{Girl} & \text{Boy} & \text{At least 1 boy} &  \text{Younger is a boy} & \frac14\\ \hline
\text{Boy} & \text{Boy} & \text{At least 1 boy} &  \text{Older is a boy} & \frac18\\ \hline
\text{Boy} & \text{Boy} & \text{At least 1 boy} &  \text{Younger is a boy} & \frac18\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

so the conditional probability given the statement "Older is a boy" of both being boys is $\dfrac{\frac18}{\frac18+\frac14}=\dfrac13$.

Similarly for the statement "Younger is a boy".

Note that in case 2, the calculation would have been different if the second question had been "*Is the older child a boy?*" so with two boys they always said the older was a boy, i.e. if the fourth row had probability $\frac14$ and the fifth row had probability $0$. The conditional probability would have become  $\frac{\frac14}{\frac14+\frac14}=\frac12$.

Comment: In other words, the conclusion in Case 2 in the question is wrong. I agree with this answer, although a more natural response from a family with two boys might be, "The boy? What on earth do you mean by 'the boy'? You didn't ask me about any particular child earlier."